# Android not throwing SocketException?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Why doesn't Android throw a `SocketException` when the socket is closed?

I get an `IOException` if there is no permission added in the manifest file for Internet but when I grant it the `Internet` permission and check my program it gets stuck at

```
Socket obj=new Socket("*****",3000);
```

if the socket is closed? Why is that?
It should not keep waiting for the socket to open instead throw an exception

```
try {
    Socket obj=new Socket("*****",3000);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How do you figure that it waits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SocketException` is a subclass of `IOException`, so the exception is being caught by your second catch clause which is the reason you don't see it.

Comment: The OP states that the socket is trying to open instead of throwing any exception at all. I don't understand your response.